# Eclipse Java Templates: How to use the parameter types in a template?

Tags: java, eclipse, templates

I would like to write a template for the Eclipse IDE. The template should use the types of the parameters of the method the template is used in so that I can for example write a template that generates a log statements like this:

```
LOG.info("myMethod(String, String)");
```

To evaluate 'myMethod' is easy (I can use `${enclosing_method}`) but I cannot evaluate the parameter types of the method (the parameter names are easy, therefor I can use `${enclosing_method_arguments}`).

Can anyone explain how I can evaluate the parameter types of the enclosing method?